# Re-defining named functions at runtime

Tags: actionscript-3

What I am trying to do is kind of odd, but I am wondering if anyone can come up with a clever way to do what I want to do.  Basically, I want to re-define a named function at runtime.  I can do this with anonymous functions, but I can't figure out a way to do it for named functions.  I want to do this so that I can implement a "spy" functionality on an object for a testing framework (a port of Jasmine to Flex).

Take, for instance, this class:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public var anonymous:Function = function():void { 
        trace("original anonymous"); 
    };

    public function named():void {
        trace("original named");
    }
}
```

I can easily re-define the anonymous function because it is just a variable.  Javascript uses this idiom a lot.

```
var testClass:TestClass = new TestClass();
testClass.anonymous = function():void { trace("overridden anonymous"); }
```

BUT, when I do the same thing for named functions, you get a compile-time error:

```
// Does not compile
testClass.named = function():void { trace("overridden named"); }
```

I tried to make it a bit more "squishy" but this leads to a runtime failure "Cannot assign to a method named on TestClass".

```
// Compiles with runtime failure
testClass["named"] = function():void { trace("overridden named"); }
```

Can anyone more clever than I come up with a way to hack this?  Can the bytecode be hijacked? Something?

Comment: I know close to nothing about actionscript but it sounds like you want to do method call interception / aspect-oriented programming. Hopefully someone has coded something for this to work with actionscript.

Comment: +1 Great Question. I tried extending the Proxy class, but didn't solve you're problem. It's late here, so my thinking might be off, but could you not just extend `TestClass` and override the named function with new functionality?

Comment: @Chris: Yes, I can always extend `TestClass` but I want to modify an object, not a class.  I am not looking to create mock objects, like that (ASMock, Mockito and Mockolate do what you are suggesting).  I want to "spy" on the functions of an object.  At least, I am trying to make the same functionality that Jasmine has (`spyOn(myObject, "theMethod")`) without requiring a new paradigm.

Comment: @Brian Genisio Ok cool. I am very interested to see what comes out of this question. If you do indeed find the answer, either through here, or externally, please let us know.

Comment: @Chris: Looking at a real hack that I was pointed to by a friend.  Use as3commons-bytecode to load the SWF, intercept the load, parse the bytecode (using the as3commons API), re-write the class with modified opcodes and pass the newly modded SWF to the loader.  Not sure I will take it that far... we'll see... there are some pretty cool options available doing that, though :)

Comment: @Brian Genisio Well it will definitely be interesting if that works. Just had a look at the as3commons-bytecode website, seems good, and reasonably straight forward. I guess it wouldn't be very difficult to break a SWF though when injecting code into it, so if it were used in a production site, extreme care would need to be taken

Comment: @Chris: I hear you on the "extreme care".  What I am doing is for a testing system... (a port of Jasmine to Flex) Doing this would be the minimum necessary to support the concept of "spies".  In my port, "spies" are already working using the Javascripty approach (variables as anonymous functions) but fails when the functions are named.  If I can just wedge something in, it will be beautiful.  If I don't, then I have to say "Everything works the same as Jasmine except for named functions, which are different"... which is certainly not the end of the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to modify an object, not a
>   class

But object doesn't contain functions, only non-static variables. I tried to use `prototype` property and replace method there, but original method still gets called instead of injected one.

About "hack" bytecode, do you mean "hack" already loaded SWF in runtime? I think it's not possible. I'm sure, though, you can parse SWF with something like as3swf, find method in bytecode, replace it and save result in new SWF.

Comment: What do you mean by "object doesn't contain functions, only non-static variables?".  Named functions are exposed like non-static variables (`theObject['funcName']()`) on an object but they are simply not writable when they are "named functions".  Even if modifying the prototype did work, that would still be modifying the class, not the instance (object).  I will look into as3swf.  Thinking that will still act on the class, though... when it is the instance that I care about.

Comment: I mean that object instance doesn't contain references to all its functions, they are resolved through the class and stored once per class, not per object. There is global function getSize(), it reports 24 bytes for an object on newmade empty class. If I add new function, this number doesn't change. If I add Number to class, it goes 8 bytes up.

Comment: For the record, you are correct.  You asked what I meant by "hack" the bytecode... I am referring to this approach, which lets you modify the bytecode (kind of) at runtime... you do it right before the code loads.  Hacky for sure.  Still pretty cool: http://zaa.tv/2011/06/360flex-denver-2011%E2%80%93planet-of-the-aops/

Answer (score 0):

I had an idea bout making a function "cache" . This might work with what you need.

Let's say you have a class "Car" with a method you need to redefine at runtime:

```
public class Car extends Sprite
{
    private var functionCache:Function;

    public function Car()
    {
        super();
    }

    public function flexibleFunction(functionBody:*=null):void{
        if(functionBody is Function){
            functionBody.call();
            functionCache=functionBody;
        } else {
            functionCache(functionBody);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Main extends Sprite
{
    private var car:Car;

    public function Main()
    {
        car = new Car();

        car.flexibleFunction(function(){trace("redefine test #1")});

        car.flexibleFunction();

        car.flexibleFunction(function(doParametersWork:String="let's see"){trace("redefine test #2: " + doParametersWork);});

        car.flexibleFunction("yes they do");

        car.flexibleFunction();

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that allows for a function to be extensible directly, but it doesn't allow for an object that wasn't written this way to work properly.  If I were to just modify the class to support changing out functions like this, I'd just go to anonymous functions.  My goal is to do this on ANY object, not just objects that were written to be modified like this.  Thanks, though.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is, once I loaded (by mistake) a SWF into my application that had the same package path and class name as an existing class in my application. The new code ran instead of the old code. Perhaps you could rewrite the class that defines the flexible function at runtime, which it seems you can do like so: http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/emit.html and then try loading it again?

Answer (score 0):

an easy way to accomplish what you want is to simply pass a new function to the original function and execute it from there:

```
package
{
//Imports
import flash.display.Sprite;

//Class
public class RedefineFunction extends Sprite
    {
    //Constructor
    public function RedefineFunction()
        {
        originalFunction();

        originalFunction(redefinedFunction);
        }

    //Original Function
    public function originalFunction(redefinition:Function = null):void
        {
        if  (redefinition != null)
            redefinition();
            else
            trace("Original Function Definition");
        }

    //Redefined Function
    private function redefinedFunction():void
        {
        trace("Redefined Function Definition")
        }
    }
}
```

traces:

```
Original Function Definition
Redefined Function Definition
```

Comment: aaaandd i just realized that ruedaminute's previous answer is pretty much the same as mine.  note to self:  read previous answers before replying.

Comment: Right :)  And it doesn't do what I need... injecting into an object that I don't have control over.  I think there is a way... doing some sort of runtime AOP tomfoolery... but how?